# Hazelcast Map Entries by Time Range

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I understand that map entries in Hazelcast, Management Center, can be queried using `m.entries` on the console. Is there a way to narrow entries by time range?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently available as a built-in feature, but I have shared your request with the product manager (I work for Hazelcast).

You would have to build the functionality yourself in the interim.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64423209/loading-sql-table-data-into-hazelcast/64426003#64426003) might be enough to get you started.
The time range could be based on when the records were added in Hazelcast, changed in Hazelcast, or perhaps in fields in the data records themselves.